# Can validate 1 date but not an array of motor[]?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have javascript validating a date. If I validate 1 date its ok but if I add another date onto the table, it doesnt work? How can I make it validate a array of motors[]. Thanks

EDIT

Thanks

Comment: Loop over all elements in your array

Comment: You may want to consider using something like jQuery to do this. Plain vanilla javaScript will get the job done but the verbosity is excruciating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make it validate a array of date[].

---

If you want to use regex you can validate the date string in one step with the following:

```
var datePattern = /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-2]?[1-9]|3[0-1])\/(19[7-9][0-9]|20[0-2][0-9]|203[0-8])$/;
```

Basically it matches the dates from `01/01/1970` to `12/31/2038`

then pass your array of dates to this function:

```
function validateDateArray(dateArray) {
    for (var date in dateArray) {
        if (!datePattern.test(dateArray[date])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KKXSZ/).

---

Alternatively you can use `Date.parse()` and check the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Add function

```
function CheckDates(inputs)
{
    var i, len;
    if (inputs.length) {
        len = inputs.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (!checkdate(inputs[i])) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return checkdate(inputs);
}
```

and replace checkdate with CheckDates in your form's onSubmit.